# Recursive template for compile-time bit mask

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, bitmask

I'm trying to create a compile-time bit mask using metaprograming techniques, my idea is to create something like this:

```
unsigned int Mask3 = Mask<2>(); // value = 0x03 = b00000000000000000000000000000011
unsigned int Mask3 = Mask<3>(); // value = 0x07 = b00000000000000000000000000000111
unsigned int Mask3 = Mask<7>(); // value = 0x7F = b00000000000000000000000001111111
```

The code that I'm trying is this:

```
template <const unsigned int N> const unsigned int Mask()
{
    if (N <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((1 << N) | Mask<N - 1>());
    }
}
```

return 1;

But it result in tons pairs of warnings:

- warning C4554: '<<' : check operator precedence for possible error
- warning C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big

And in the end, the compile error:

- error C1202:  recursive type or function dependency context too complex.

So, I deduce that the recursivity never ends and falls into a compiler infinite loop but I'm don't understanding WHY.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do something like "int result = 0; for(i=0; i<N; i++){ result = result << 1; result += 1; } return result; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, you're depending on a runtime check to
stop a compile time recursion, which can't work.  More importantly,
perhaps, for what you want to do, is that you're defining a function,
which has no value until you call it.  So even after you stop the
recursion with a specialization, you still have a nested sequence of
functions, which will be called at runtime.

If you want full compile time evaluation, you must define a static data
member of a class template, since that's the only way a compile time
constant can appear in a template.  Something like:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct Mask
{
    static unsigned int const value = (1 << (N - 1)) | Mask<N - 1>::value;
};

template <>
struct Mask<0>
{
    static unsigned int const value = 0;
};
```

(I've also corrected the numerical values you got wrong.)

Of course, you don't need anything this complicated.  The following
should do the trick:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct Mask
{
    static unsigned int const value = (1 << (N + 1)) - 1;
};

template <>
struct Mask<0>
{
    static unsigned int const value = 0;
};
```

(You still need the specialization for 0.  Otherwise, 0 means all bits
set.)

Finally, of course: to access the value, you need to write something
like `Mask<3>::value`.  (You might want to wrap this in a macro.)

Comment: Mark this as accepted answer only because explains fair and clear how to do in the temeplate form, but the best answer is the one fo Sander De Dycker.

Comment: Except that the one from Sander De Dycker still involves a function call, so the value isn't a constant.  (With C++11, however, it _could_ be declared `constexpr`.)  And it fails for `N == 0`.  (Otherwise, it corresponds to my second solution, above.)

Comment: If N >= 32, my compiler complains that it is not standards compliant, even if I made it `unsigned long long`. Command: **`clang++-3.3 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -pedantic Mask.cpp`** (The flags standard for strictly C++11). Result: `Mask.cpp:7:48: error: in-class initializer for static data member is not a constant expression; folding it to a constant is a GNU extension [-Werror,-Wgnu]` **`static unsigned long long const value = (1 << (N + 1)) - 1;`** `Mask.cpp:19:10: note: in instantiation of template class 'Mask<32>' requested here` **`cout << Mask<32>::value << endl;`**

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- I wonder what exactly it is complaining about.  The expression certainly meets the requirements for an integral constant expression in C++03, and is widely used as such.  `N` is const, as is `1`, and all of the operators used are allowed in const expressions.

Comment: Yes, I also wonder. I think a possible reason is that the compiler doesn't do `<<` out of 32-bit range during compilation (I have no idea if this is standard behaviour or not). Try this too with your compiler (turn on all warnings and standards complaint): **`static std::int64_t const my_min = -9223372036854775808LL;`**. Mine (clang++-3.3) complains with `min.cpp:5:37: error: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned [-Werror]`. If I change it to **`-9223372036854775808ULL`** (Notice the 'U' added), there's no error. I think it's related to the intermediate values during compilation.

Comment: I guess this is what happens when compiling my above example: If I write **`-9223372036854775808LL`**, the compiler treats it as **`-(9223372036854775808LL)`**, which is certainly out of range. If I write **`-9223372036854775808ULL`**, it gets the value **`9223372036854775808ULL`** in an **`unsigned`** container first (which is sufficient to hold the constant), and then change it to negative (and then the type changes to **`signed`** at the same time). I have to say that it is so *COUNTER-INTUITIVE*!!!

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- Of course.  I should have seen it earlier.  On almost all implementations today, `1 << 32` is undefined behavior, since `1` will have type `int`, which is 32 bits.  If you want to generate `unsigned long long`, you need `1ULL << 32`.  (The fact that you use the expression to initialize an `unsigned long long` has no effect on the types used in the expression.)

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- Yes.  There are no negative literals; -42 is a two token sequence.  This is the way C++ is designed, and on a two's complement architecture (almost all today), there will be one negative value which simply cannot be expressed as a literal.  But you're wrong on one point, `-9223372036854775808ULL` does not result in a negative, signed number; the type is still `unsigned long long`, with the value `9223372036854775808ULL`.  If `long long` is 64 bits, the results of converting this value to a `long long` are implementation defined.

Comment: Yes, you're correct! I overlooked the type of the literal `1`. Now my code compiles without any problem. My implementation allows the user to specified which of the (integral) types the mask is defined, so I must write **`static T const value = (static_cast<T>(1) << N) - static_cast<T>(1);`**, where `T` is the type parameter of the integral type.

Comment: For the 2nd one, I tried with **`static std::int64_t const my_min_1 = 9223372036854775808ULL;`** and **`static std::int64_t const my_min_2 = -9223372036854775808ULL;`**, both didn't issue a compiler warning. I didn't look up the standard, but since the value is stored in an `int64_t`, it can't be `9223372036854775808` - the datatype is not wide enough to store it. And since the machine uses 2's complement, it's quite reasonable to say that the binary value `1000...(63 0's)` becomes `-9223372036854775808`. The same behaviour is observed in **`static std::int32_t const my_min_3 = 2147483648;`**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49164/discussion-between-james-kanze-and-asuka-kenji-siu-ching-pong)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't need to be recursive. This should work just fine :

```
template <const unsigned int N> const unsigned int Mask()
{
    return ((1 << N) - 1);
}
```

It doesn't even need to be a template really. An (inlined) function is ok.

Note that if you want to support any value of `N`, specifically `N >= sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT`, you probably want to treat those as a special case.

Answer (score 3):

A template is created at compile time, but you are relying on run time behavior to stop the recursion.

For example, if you instantiate Mask<2>, it is going to use Mask<1>, which is going to use Mask<0>, which is going to use Mask<-1>, etc.

You have a runtime check for N being <= 1, but this doesn't help when it's compiling.  It still creates an infinite sequence of functions.

Answer (score 3):

To blunt template instantiation recursion you need to introduce one explicit specialization:

```
template <0> const unsigned int Mask()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Your recursion never ends, because compiler tries to generate template implementation for both if-branches. So, when it generates Mask<0> it also generates Mask<0xffffffff> and so on

Answer (score 2):

C++11 -- no recursion or templates:

```
constexpr unsigned mask(unsigned N) { return unsigned(~(-1<<N)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

So far the answers only addressed the second error (C1202), but you asked more than that.

Warning C4554 is caused by a Microsoft compiler bug involving template parameters and the << operator.  So, (1 << N) generates a warning.  If N were an ordinary parameter, there would be no warning of course.

The very simple workaround is to use (1 << (N)) instead of (1 << N), and C4554 goes away!