# Generating bit mask at compile time

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, constexpr

I would like to generate various bit masks at compile time:

`0x11111111` or `0x1111111111111111`

`0xF0F0F0F0` or `0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0`

The size will be dependant on a type, either 32 bits or 64 bits.

ex:

```
template <typename T> genMask(unsigned char templt) {
  ....
};

genMask<uint32_t>(0xF0);
genMask<uint64_t>(0xF0);
```

The first call should generate `0xF0F0F0F0` while the second call to genMask
should generate `0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0`

Currently I have these hard coded.

Any ideas here would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here is an old-school way of doing it:

`#define MASK(b) ((T(-1) / 0xFF) * (b))`

where T is the type.

Comment: I think this is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778763/recursive-template-for-compile-time-bit-mask

Comment: The values you show are merely `std::numeric_limits<T>::max() / 0xFF * 0x11` and `std::numeric_limits<T>::max() / 0xFF * 0xF0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you can accomplish this with [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast):

```cpp
template <std::unsigned_integral T>
constexpr T genMask(unsigned char templt) {
  std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(T)> mask;
  mask.fill(templt);
  return std::bit_cast<T>(mask);
}
```

If you want to ensure this function may only return compile-time constants, you can use the [`consteval` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) instead, but it is sufficient to achieve the same effect by calling the function above in the initializer of a [`constexpr` variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr#constexpr_variable), or as a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments).

Comment: To get this to compile,  I needed to initialize the mask:
`std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(T)> mask = {0};`

Comment: Note that `std::array` has its own `fill()` method that is `constexpr` since C++20: `mask.fill(templt);`

Comment: @Jacko works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/K4qe1qsqW

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to build an array of the bytes you want and then cast those bits into the destination type with `std::bit_cast`.  That would give you

```
template <typename T> 
constexpr T genMask(unsigned char val) 
{
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(T)];
    for (auto& e : bytes)
        e = val;
    return std::bit_cast<T>(bytes);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << genMask<uint32_t>(0xF0) << " " << genMask<uint64_t>(0xF0);
}
```

which outputs

```
f0f0f0f0 f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0
```

---

If you can't use `std::bit_cast` then you can do the bit manipulation yourself like

```
template <typename T> 
constexpr T genMask(unsigned char val) 
{
    T ret{val};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) - 1; ++i)
    {
        ret <<= 8;
        ret |= val;
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: So, currently I have
`#define FOO 0xf0f0f0f0`
How would I rewrite that using genMask as above ?

Comment: @Jacko `inline constexpr auto FOO = genMask<type_desired>(0xF0);`

Answer (score 3):

So you want to multiply your 1 byte pattern by `0x01010101...` (repeated for the appropriate length of your type).

You'll notice that if you had your pattern be `0xFF`, then you end up with `0xFFFFFFFF...`, or the maximum value of that type, so dividing by `0xFF` will get your pattern with `0x01`.

With that said:

```cpp
template <typename T> constexpr T genMask(unsigned char templt) {
    constexpr T multiplier{std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max() / 0xFFu};
    return multiplier * T{templt};
}

static_assert(genMask<std::uint32_t>(0xF0) == 0xF0F0F0F0);
static_assert(genMask<std::uint64_t>(0xA2) == 0xA2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
template <typename T>
T genMask(unsigned char templt) {
  return (T)(0x0101010101010101ULL * templt);
};
```